# Pandas Series to count values in another Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a series in Pandas (s1) to calculate the number of instances of those fixed numbers (1-14) against the column ('d1') in the original DataFrame.
What I want is shown here (Times);

```
s1    Last   Times  
 1      2      72   
 2     34      59   
 3     15      48   
 4      0      30   
 5     13      39   
 6      4      28   
 7      6      34   
 8      3      31   
 9     17      17   
10     32      15   
11      1      15   
12    102      14   
13      9      13   
14     51       7
```

Sample of csv file is here;

```
   date d1  d2  d3  d4  d5  d6  d7
17/12/22    9   10  12  15  24  32  33
17/12/22    3   9   13  17  27  32  46
17/12/22    4   12  13  19  25  26  29
17/12/22    5   12  14  30  35  40  49
17/12/22    1   4   8   11  15  38  44
17/12/22    8   16  17  29  34  37  42
17/12/22    3   9   16  20  28  33  43
17/12/22    9   12  14  19  29  44  46
17/12/22    1   15  19  27  28  37  38
17/12/29    22  23  26  35  37  39  47
18/01/05    1   3   13  15  28  36  49
18/01/12    1   8   16  19  26  34  41
18/01/19    9   18  25  30  39  40  43
```

Running the code, produces no errors but I am at a loss how to loop from 1 to 14 and tally the number of times the number has occurred in the dataset (d1). My code is as shown.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.max_rows = 999

df = pd.read_csv("lmax_full.csv", index_col=False)

df.drop('date', axis=1, inplace=True)  # count the times drawn under 'd1'
count_dA = df.d1.value_counts()
print(count_dA.head())  # print the count of 'd1'
s1 = pd.Series(range(1, 15), index=None)  
print(s1)


# using Series s1 from 1-14 apply a loop count across all rows on 'd1'
# to get counts of each number in s1
def count_d1(count):
    for i in s1:
        count = s1.apply(pd.count_dA.value_counts)
        i += 1
    return count

print(count_dA)
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output specific to the input data? I do not see you mentioning `Last` column in your code. How is that computed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand , you can follow below approach based on sample data:

```
ser = pd.concat([df['d1'].value_counts(), pd.Series([np.nan]*14, index=range(1,15), name='d1')]).sort_index()
ser = ser[~ser.index.duplicated()].fillna(0).astype(int)[:14]
s1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Times':ser
})
```

Output:

```
Times
1   4
2   0
3   0
4   1
5   0
6   0
7   0
8   1
9   3
10  0
11  0
12  0
13  0
14  0
```

Comment: Yes, works. I pasted your code into mine and it gives the expected result. I have to try to understand how it works though. Is it vectorized?

Comment: Something here;
If I run 'count_dA.head(20)'over whole dataset
then
12 = 14 times
13 = 13 times
14 = 7 times

The new code shows

12 = 0 times
13 = 0 times
14 = 0 times

Comment: My guess here and I could be wrong, is that the code is not picking up the full 'd1' values across all the rows till the end of the column 'd1' The times indicated top of my question are the correct value counts.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The output here is for the sample input that you have given in your question. Glad it worked out. @Robert

Comment: Harv, what is the code mod. required to allow the output to be generated over the whole column of 'd1'. As I tried to explain, when running the code now, gives zeros for 12,13,14 for all 450 rows. Values should be 14,13,7 respectively. Please see the part above where 'What I want is shown here' is.

Comment: @Robert, the above code would work for the whole `d1` column. Can you post the results that you get with `df['d1'].value_counts()` for all your 450 rows? I am certain that if you run the above code with your dataframe, it would show the correct results. Also, I see you mentioned, that for top 20 rows, 12 appears 14 times, 13 appears 13 times and 14 appears 7 times . How is that possible, the numbers do not add up to 20. Are you talking about more than 20 rows?

Comment: Harv, here are the value_counts for d1 over the whole 450 rows; I left off the rest of your code                                                              1     72
2     60
3     47
5     40
7     35
8     31
4     30
6     28
9     17
10    15
11    15
12    14
13    13
14     7
16     5
19     5
15     4
17     4
18     3
23     3
26     2
20     1
21     1
22     1
33     1
Name: d1, dtype: int64

Comment: Sorry Harv, over 454 rows, but the values are correct over the whole range of d1 for 454 rows. I wish I could somehow get full csv to view, rather than just the sample.